# NokoGiri Error trying to use MiniTest-Rails-capybara

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, minitest

when trying to run

```
rake minitest:features
```

for the first time in my rails 3 app on my osx 10.8.4 machine i get a nokogiri error

```
/Users/willbarker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/willbarker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: 

/Users/willbarker/.bundler/tmp/60826/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (LoadError)

  Referenced from: /Users/willbarker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle

  Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Is there a way to resolve that? Is it an issue with the gem or my underlying system?(which seems to find a way to trip over nokogiri faily often)

UPDATE - The lock file

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    active_admin_editor (1.1.0)
      activeadmin (>= 0.4.0)
      ejs
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    activeadmin (0.6.0)
      arbre (>= 1.0.1)
      bourbon (>= 1.0.0)
      devise (>= 1.1.2)
      fastercsv
      formtastic (>= 2.0.0)
      inherited_resources (>= 1.3.1)
      jquery-rails (>= 1.0.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.0)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arbre (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1)
    better_errors (0.9.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bourbon (3.1.8)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
      thor
    builder (3.0.4)
    callsite (0.0.11)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    chunky_png (1.2.8)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.1)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    compass (0.12.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-rails (1.0.3)
      compass (>= 0.12.2, < 0.14)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.0.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    ejs (1.1.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    formtastic (2.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    high_voltage (1.2.4)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httparty (0.11.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    inherited_resources (1.4.0)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.9)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_request (0.2.7)
      callsite
      rack-contrib
      railties
    meta_search (1.1.3)
      actionpack (~> 3.1)
      activerecord (~> 3.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.1)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    mime-types (1.23)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    minitest-capybara (0.4.1)
      capybara (~> 2.0)
      minitest (~> 4.0)
      rake
    minitest-metadata (0.4.0)
      minitest (~> 4.7)
    minitest-rails (0.9.2)
      minitest (~> 4.7)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    minitest-rails-capybara (0.10.0)
      capybara (~> 2.0)
      minitest-capybara (~> 0.4)
      minitest-metadata (~> 0.4)
      minitest-rails (~> 0.9.1)
    multi_json (1.7.7)
    multi_xml (0.5.4)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (3.5.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    pg (0.16.0)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rb_wunderground (0.1.2)
      hashie (~> 1.2)
      httparty (~> 0.9)
      json (~> 1.7)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (0.9.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    zurb-foundation (4.3.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_admin_editor
  activeadmin
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  compass-rails
  high_voltage
  jquery-rails (= 2.3.0)
  meta_request
  minitest-rails
  minitest-rails-capybara
  paperclip (~> 3.0)
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.13)
  rb_wunderground
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  thin
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  zurb-foundation
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Gemfile.lock file?

Comment: thanks for looking at this. Question updated with the lockfile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade libxml2 and libxslt. If you are using Brew you can do the following:

```
$ brew install libxml2 libxslt
$ brew link libxml2 libxslt
```

See the [Nokogiri documentation](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) for more information.

Comment: Warning: libxml2-2.9.1 already installed
Warning: libxslt-1.1.28 already installed

Comment: Thats the error message when i try that. Do i need to update instead of install? Can't find info on how to do that.

Comment: looking at nokogiri site, 1.6 comes bundled with the libxml & libxslt - seems odd this is falling over

Comment: running brew doctor gives me:  Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

    libxml2
good idea? or no?